# Firestore cloud functions accept multipart/form-data?

Tags: firebase, express, multipartform-data, google-cloud-functions, multer

Someone knows if the firestore cloud functions http requests support multipart/form-data, I'm trying to send images to cloudinary through this with help of express and multer, for the moment it doesn't works to me, except if I run it locally

Comment: If you're asking for help with specific code - posting the code and any errors you're getting can help us help you figure out how to do what you want.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 7):

Please consult the documentation for Cloud Functions with respect to the [handling of various types of input](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests).  It has custom handlers for a few content types.

In particular, look at the section on [handling multipart form uploads](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_multipart_form_uploads).  You won't be able to apply middleware (such as multer) that automatically deals with that type.  You'll have to parse req.rawBody yourself.  The code in that section shows how to use another module called busboy to handle things.

Unfortunately, the local emulator doesn't have all these special handlers in place yet, so your code running locally doesn't fully emulate the Cloud Functions environment.  Feel free to [file a bug request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) for that and add your voice to others who are experiencing the same.